# Fluent validation Db password with user input

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, fluentvalidation

I would like to know what can I do to have properly running my code.
I want to validate the oldPassword enter by the user in the form against the password that is stored in the db. Is they are the same is good to go if are different raise an error.
So far I have this but I have errors and don't pretty sure how to fix it.
I have the function IsSameAsOldPassword but i dont know how to send the parameters.

```
RuleSet(() => RuleFor(x => x.OldPassword)
                    .Must((x) => IsSameAsOldPassword(x.Id, x.OldPassword))
                    .WithMessage("Old password incorrect"), RuleSets.Update);

private bool IsSameAsOldPassword(Guid id, string oldPassword)
{
    var user = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());
    return _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user.Result, oldPassword).Result;
}
```

Any improvement to the code will be welcome.

Comment: You would usually do an actual password check. Because _nobody stores plaintext passwords in a db_, you can only check whatever the user entered passes the password check (with salting, hashing, the full monty).

Comment: btw: `return _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user.Result, oldPassword).Result;` - Don't do this. If you have an async API go async all the way. See also: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/async.html

Comment: Im not storing plain text, i just want to validate that the old password enter is ok. How can i do it. Thanks

Comment: Do whatever your login does to verify a password against that db entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution, hope this help someone else, we just need to remove the field. the final solution will be like this:

```
RuleSet(() =>
{
    RuleFor(x => x)
        .MustAsync((x, cancellation) => IsSameAsOldPassword(x))
        .WithMessage("Old password incorrect");
}, RuleSets.Update);


private async Task<bool> IsSameAsOldPassword(UserSetInputModel userInputModel)
{
    userInputModel.fieldToUse
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).